# Command line works fine in CMD cant get it to work through batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I have a command that works fine in CMD but if i try and save it as a bat it quickly opens and closes CMD and nothing happens.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 0 /f"
```

--

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d user /f"
```

--

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /d 12345 /f"
```

These are the 3 lines and I cant work out how to get a batch to run it.

Comment: You certainly need to remove the closing last character double quote from each line. Also because you're modifying/adding to HKLM, I'd recommend running the batch file as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment, *(you should run this as administrator)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "rKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Reg Add "%rKey%" /V AutoAdminLogon /D 0 /F > Nul
Reg Add "%rKey%" /V DefaultUserName /D user /F > Nul
Reg Add "%rKey%" /V DefaultPassword /D 12345 /F >Nul
```

*the `> Nul` may be omitted, if you want to see the returned message*

Comment: Not too sure what I'm doing wrong,  I used what you recommended and ran it as admin but it still did not edit/add it to the registry.

Comment: Do you mean that you right clicked on it and selected `Run as administrator`?

Comment: Yes I did that, I never got it sorted as an individual batch but somehow I got it working as part of a larger script which was the original plan, thank  you for your help with this